# In need of a Tool/template that posts downloads similar to Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, web-applications

I'm not even sure what they call this or these kinds of tools.

But I'm in need of a tool that works similar to Wordpress that works like a blog. However, instead of blogging I want to post downloadable content to my website with images and maybe a description of what the download is. Like a blog, newer posts/content show up at the top older ones go to the bottom and are archived.

What do they call these tools? Can anyone provide links or point me in a direction so I can even begin to research something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMS - Content Management System. Wordpress lets you do what you're looking for though, just look through the VARIOUS plugins available.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from using wordpress to do this.  Including links in "posts" or "entries" is easy, and you can make your own custom post types if you wish.  That would make the post form more tailored to your needs.  For instance, instead of a title and body, you could have a title, download link, featured image, and description fields in the custom post type.

Or even more simply, use the body of a default post to include a link and a description, and designate a featured image.

Do you have any knowledge of php?